# NGINX and React :net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I created a react demo with create-react-app,it runs at `http://localhost:3000`,and I use NGINX as reverse proxy,`nginx.conf` is like this:

```
server {
        listen       3001;
        server_name  localhost;


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }


        location /api { 
            proxy_pass  http://192.168.33.3:8080;    
        }  

 }
```

when I access `http://localhost:3001`,there is an error:

[image: ![clipboard.png](/img/bVblSu5)]

What should I do?

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem already?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add root in your server pointing to react bundle:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/bundle
}
```

Comment: where is bundle.js?I can not find this file

Comment: First create bundle and specify the path of that build folder in your root